# executing make parallel does not compile

Tags: c++, c, makefile

I am working on a quite complex and big C/C++ project.
When compiling the project using `make -j8`, it does not compile, although it compiles when running `make` plainly, without setting parallel jobs. It does not happen every time, but it happens very often. 
As I mentioned, the project is big and complex and I fear that the dependencies are not set right in the make files. Do you think that's the issue? Any ideas how I could correct it? And why would it happen *only* very often and not every time?

---

I forgot to add the make output:

```
foo.so: file not recognized: File truncated  
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status   
make[3]: ___ Error 1   
make[3]: Leaving directory ___  
make[2]: ___ Error 2   
make[2]: Leaving directory ___  
=====================================================================   make[1]: ___ Error 1   
make[1]: Leaving directory ___   
make: ___ Error 1   
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....   
make[3]: Leaving directory ___ make[2]: Leaving directory ___  
=====================================================================   make[1]: Leaving directory ___
```

Comment: Do you have any "sub"-Makefiles?

Comment: Apearently the `foo.so' was not add as dependency of linking, and the make in a serial invocation would create it anyway in some stage...

Comment: @E_net4 If you mean makefiles calling other makefiles, yes I do. It's like a tree structure

Comment: @WojciechFrohmberg foo.so is not always the same so. Sometimes it is called a.so, sometimes b.so. It breaks the compilation at different stages. Sometimes the make output does not make much sense either, because it gets mixed from 8 different jobs, which is an expected disadvantage of distributing the compilation

Comment: @lulijeta Yes because it problably depends which dependency isn't compiled at the time of linking...

Comment: @WojciechFrohmberg It makes sense. How can I check the dependencies? I mean, the shared objects are there, since it has no problem compiling serial. It must be about timing / sequence of compilation of different parts. The problem is that the project is big and I lack the overview to all parts of it. Is there a way to see or detect the lacking dependencies?

Comment: @lulijeta: The rules that create the a.so, b.so etc should look like `a.so: dependencies_of_a.so` and so on. The linking rule should be `executable: a.so b.so foo.so ...`